# Exception when trying to execute query on large library from client object model

Tags: 2013, client-object-model

I have a document library with ~50,000 documents in it. I have a Client Object Model query which retrieves the `ListItem`s in the document library. This query previously worked when the document library was much smaller, but is now throwing a `WebException` - (503) Server Unavailable. The status property of the exception contains a `System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError`.

I'm hoping this is just a timeout or size limit that can be fixed by modifying some configuration somewhere. Does anyone have any advice as to what configuration I might change to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many items are you returning in your query? It could be that you are hitting the List View threshold for the web application. For SP 2010 and 2013 the List View threshold is 5000. And, you will start getting warnings when there are 3000 items in the list. This is the maximum number of items that can be involved in a database operation.

To get around it, you have a few options:

- Limit the number of items returned by your query. You can do this by refining you CAML query to only return the items that you really are interested in or, by adding a RowLimit element to your view xml in combination with ListItemCollectionPosition (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitemcollectionposition.aspx) and processing the items in batches.
- Disable throttling for the list. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.enablethrottling.aspx
- Increase the throttling threshold for the entire web app. In SharePoint 2010 you'll find it in Central Admin, Application Management, Manage web applications, select a web app, on the ribbon, under General Settings, select resource throttling.

Comment: Resource throttling is off for the entire Web Application. The list view thresholds have been set to enormous values as well. Still get the exception. The query must return all 50,000 items.

Comment: but if you throttle the query, does it work? If so your web service is probably choking on 50,000 items in the full call. Those thresholds are there for a reason.  If it were me I would push back on the requirement to return 50,000 items in a web service.

Comment: You're using the Include() syntax to limit the fields returned, right? That would help limit the amount of data going across the wire.

Comment: I've tried that, but no success. I may have to resort to fetching the data via the server object model and using a custom web service to return it.

Comment: Try limiting the numbers of items returned by your query to 1000 with the RowLimit element in your view XML. If you still have the same issue then the problem lies elsewhere. If it does run without errors, then try using RowLimit in conjuction with ListItemCollectionPosition (another example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee534956(v=office.14).aspx) to run your query in batches. If you need to retrieve 50k plus items in one go then I would question the architecture of your application as you'll always have performance issues.

Comment: Also, do you have access to the ULS logs? They should give you a clearer idea of what the actual error is.

Comment: Paging the records worked. This is just what I needed, thanks.